# WMI, VMWare: Wrong ChassisTypes from Win32_SystemEnclosure

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, wmi, chassis

On Windows 7 installation on **VMWare**, following WMI query:

```
Select ChassisTypes from Win32_SystemEnclosure
```

is returning **1** (Other), and not expected value **3** (Desktop). It returns correct type on HyperV virtual machine, however.

What can be done to get correct Chassis-type on VMWare' VM? Any other WMI class, registry?

Comment: Vmware is a company which makes esX, vSphere,vmware fusion, vmware player, vmware workstation, .... What program are you using? PLease mention that in the question and retag occordingly.

Comment: VMware Workstation Pro 12 for Windows